# Logging function execution with all details?

Tags: php

For instance: there is a function like given below:

```
public function something(string $fnStrArgument, int $fnIntArgument) : void 
{

    $this->aFunction($fnStrArgument);
    $this->anotherFunction($fnIntArgument);

}
```

Is there **a standard** or **a reflection method** that i can learn ***"something()"*** used those functions while being executed ?

Eg.

```
Format: 


$this->something function executed with =>

                 aFunction with argument(s) < $fnStrArgument value >
                 anotherFunction with argument(s) < $fnIntArgument value >
```

My request sounds like a traceback but I would like to know how can i do this properly? I just want to learn how can i **log** method executions like given above. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you looking for a profiler tool like XHProf or Blackfire? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase yes it's something like this, thanks :). But i couldn't see enough examples on php.net documentation... i will do more reasearch.